# Can 01Knapsack algorithm with solution printed using O(n) space?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

With dynamic programming, `01 knapsack` can be solved using the formula:

`f(v) = max(f(v), f(v-cost(i)+w(i))` with V reverse enumeration.

But if I want to record which item is put into the knapsack, I need a two dimensional array to record the item index.

I'm not sure can `01Knapsack` use `O(n)` space to get the solution of items put in the knapsack?

Comment: You can trade time for space.

Answer (score 1):

It is always true that the solution for a DP with N states can be reconstructed with at most O(N) additional memory. The way to do this is to create an additional array of the same size as the states array and store what move you did for each for the states. In the case of this particular problem, you will have to record if `f(v)` or `f(v-cost(i)+w(i))` was optimal.

Comment: Actually `01 knapsack` has VN states, when calculated, `f(i)(v)` it just uses `f(i-1)(v)` and `f(i-1)(v-cost(i))`, so reverse enumeration can save space to O(V).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the formula is

```
f(w) = max(f(w), f(w - w[i]) + v[i])
```

It means that for weight `w` we should try to take i-th element, so we should take as much value as possible for the rest weight `w - w[i]` (it is `f(w - w[i])`) and also i-th element provides value `v[i]`.

You can add another array `choice` and check whether actually `f(w - w[i]) + v[i] > f(w)` and if it is the case update `choice[w] = i`.

Then you spend `O(W)` memory and can easily restore the set of your choice.